# Javascript create HTML JqueryMobile range input from button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got some javascript code on a HTML page that creates a dropbox with a range of 1-10 when a button is clicked that looks like this:

```
if (type==1){

 var drop = document.createElement("SELECT"); 

 for ( i = 0, x = 1 ; i < 10; i++ ) {

 drop.options[drop.options.length] = new Option(x,x);
 x++;
} 

   myDiv.appendChild(drop);
    }
```

And this works fine, however I don't want to use a dropbox anymore, instead I want to generate a Jquery mobile slider with HTML code that looks like this:

```
<input type="range" name="slider-fill" id="slider-fill" value="0" min="0" max="10" data-theme="b" data-track-theme="c" data-highlight="true" />
```

After playing around with my code for a while I haven't had any success with actually creating the slider, if anyone has some advice for how I should go about this, it would be very appreciated.

Comment: We need a lot more information to try to give help on this, can you provide your full code. Can you provide any errors etc

Comment: Also it's recommended that you read http://api.jquerymobile.com/slider/, the documentation covers how to create widgets in code.